# PERL CTRL-D not stoping user input

Tags: perl, user-input, eof

Learning perl I found that in this case CTRL+D is not working to stop user input. Its working in others scripts so probably is something realted with the code itself.

I was reading on the internet about EOF but anything seems to work for me.

Thank you in advance and best Regards.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Dime tus numeros\n";

@numb =<STDIN>;


$cua = 0;
$count = 0;
$array = "@numb";

$max = @numb; #tamaño array
$joined = join('',@numb); #metemos array en sacalar juntandolo sin espacios
$joined = $original; #guardamos el num original


$diff = 999 - $joined;

for ($i=0; i<=$max;$i++){ #es <= por que el arraylenght no empieza en 0

    $sumatotal += $numb[$i]; #vamos sumando cada elemento del array
}


print "Has añadido los numeros $array. \n";
print "Combiandose en $joined que sumados entre si dan:$sumatotal \n";
print "La diferencia entre $joined y 999 es $cua\n";
```

Comment: "*anything seems to work for me.*" ... That's great. Now, what is your question?

Comment: That has nothing to do with Perl. Ctrl-D is an OS thing. On Linux and other unix systems, unless you reconfigured the key, Ctrl-D at the start of a line will send an EOF signal. Perl will respond to that signal by returning from `<STDIN>`.

Comment: And, on DOSish systems, `CTRL-Z` signals EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem,
For loop never ends cause of bad declaration of the second i wich should be $i, this put the execution in an endless loop.

```
for ($i=0; i<=$max;$i++)
```

Comment: Alternatively: `for my $i ( 0..$max )`